# Mysql View with like condition

Tags: mysql

I have a database that keeps some people information.

I am sending the following query:

```
(select 'NUMBER OF BRAND PARTNERS ACTIVE PROMOTERS' AS `NUMBER OF ACTIVE PROMOTERS`,count(*) AS `COUNT( * )` from `Registration_Summary` where promoter not like "bw%")
```

and it works perfectly, but whenever I create a view to hold this command, the "where promoter not like "bw%"" part is totally ignored, why ?! so strange ?! as if view can not have "like" condition !!

my view command is:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS
(select 'NUMBER OF BRAND PARTNERS ACTIVE PROMOTERS' AS `NUMBER OF ACTIVE PROMOTERS`,count(*) AS `COUNT( * )` from `Registration_Summary` where promoter not like "bw%")
```

---

I think my question should be how do I create a view based on another view with a "where like" statement?

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes?, with: `not like 'bw%'`

Comment: @ypercube That's correct SQL, but MySQL allows both single and double quotes.

Comment: @imad: What does the `SHOW CREATE VIEW test` return?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: You are right, under default settings, single or double quotes can be used.

Comment: i have tried single and double quotes, but still same result. Well, it works without the create view !!

Comment: *"the ... part is totally ignored"*. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the commands run as if I do not have the where condition, so it shows all the data in the table

Comment: @imad: So, `SELECT * FROM test` shows a count of the whole `Registration_Summary` table? And you do have rows where `promoter` column starts with `bw`?

Answer (score 2):

I think that something else might be going wrong. Replicating your question like:

```
create table `Registration_Summary` (
    id integer primary key, 
    promoter varchar(200)
);

insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (1, 'bar1');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (2, 'bar2');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (3, 'bar3');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (4, 'foo1');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (5, 'foo1');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (6, 'foo1');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (7, 'foo1');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (8, 'afoo1');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (9, 'bfoo1');
insert into `Registration_Summary` (id, promoter) values (10, 'cfoo1');
```

Selecting from the Registration table

```
select * from `Registration_Summary` where promoter like 'foo%';
```

Will produce the following output

```
+----+----------+
| id | promoter |
+----+----------+
|  4 | foo1     |
|  5 | foo1     |
|  6 | foo1     |
|  7 | foo1     |
+----+----------+
```

and

```
select * from `Registration_Summary` where promoter not like 'foo%';
```

will produce the following

```
+----+----------+
| id | promoter |
+----+----------+
|  1 | bar1     |
|  2 | bar2     |
|  3 | bar3     |
|  8 | afoo1    |
|  9 | bfoo1    |
| 10 | cfoo1    |
+----+----------+
```

So creating the view like you have

```
create or replace view testview as (select 'NUMBER OF BRAND PARTNERS ACTIVE PROMOTERS' AS `NUMBER OF ACTIVE PROMOTERS`,count(*) AS `COUNT( * )`  from `Registration_Summary` where promoter not like 'foo%');
```

and then selecting from the view

```
SELECT * FROM testview;
```

Produces the correct output which is

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| NUMBER OF ACTIVE PROMOTERS                | COUNT( * ) |
+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| NUMBER OF BRAND PARTNERS ACTIVE PROMOTERS |          6 |
+-------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: This is what makes me crazy !! the select command works totally fine, but whenever I put it in a view, it give me the wrong answer which is 10 instead of 6 as in your example. What could cause this problem ?! could it be from the phpmyadmin of name.com which I am using ?!

Comment: @imad I tried replicating with a local phpMyAdmin v3.4.5 that I have but again I couldn't. If I try to create the view through the SQL window or executing the query and using the "Create View" option on the bottom again the view is created normally and presents the correct results. Perhaps it would be a good idea to also test in a local copy (if you have one).

Comment: I cannot use a local DB, I am forced to use the public DB on name.com

Answer (score 0):

I think I knew what is the problem. I am issuing the where condition on another view not a table, I think that is why I am not getting the correct answer. Am I right ?

I still did not solve the problem, but when I create view for a select command using a table it works, but when I use it to select from another view, it gives a wrong answer when using where statement.

Comment: I would say you are right if this solves your problem. Does it? If yes you should make that clear in this answer. Otherwise is it no answer.

Comment: @imad: You still haven't shown us what the `SHOW CREATE VIEW view_name` returns.

Comment: If we take the example written by user1112145, SHOW CREATE VIEW view_name will return 10 instead of 6

Answer (score 0):

Replying to an old thread because I just ran into what might have been the same issue.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS like_test;

CREATE TABLE like_test (
     id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique ID'
    ,textvalue varchar(64) COLLATE ucs2_bin NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=ucs2 COLLATE=ucs2_bin;

INSERT INTO like_test (textvalue)
VALUES
 ('foofoo')
,('foobar')
,('barfoo')
,('barbar');

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_like_test;

CREATE VIEW view_like_test AS
SELECT
     id
    ,textvalue
FROM like_test
WHERE textvalue NOT LIKE 'foo%';

SHOW CREATE VIEW view_like_test;
```

After MySQL's internal mangling, the view has stripped the LIKE condition:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `symbols_mgr`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view_like_test` AS
    select 
        `like_test`.`id` AS `id`,
        `like_test`.`textvalue` AS `textvalue`
    from
        `like_test`
    where
        (not ((`like_test`.`textvalue` like '')))
```

The charset/collation is causing the LIKE condition to be emptied - so maybe the OP had a similar table structure.

I'm on version 5.1 - maybe this has stopped being an issue since then. Had a quick go on 5.5 and the LIKE condition changed to this:

```
(not ((`like_test`.`textvalue` like '\0\0\0f\0\0\0o\0\0\0o\0\0\0%')))
```

If it's viable, making the data more vanilla for MySQL (e.g. latin/ascii) might be the easiest way around the problem. Or you could change the view like so:

```
(not ((`like_test`.`textvalue` like 'foo%' collate utf8_bin)))
```

...where you're specifying a collation.